# How to insert attributes into a WFS using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

So I have a web app that's running and is able to add polygon to existing Postgis tables by getting data from Geoserver. I need the following one specific bit of functionality added:

I want to allow users to also be able to add attribute information to each polygon on the map interface. As in, each polygon they draw on the map, there needs to be something that allows the user to also enter some text data to the column.

I've tried reading a few questions in here but none of them who make more than one column to add attribute information.
I have three column for user add attributes information (name,city,area).

How to do this?

The bit I have for loading and posting the WFS polygon features is:

```js
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
      var url = "http://localhost:8070/geoserver/geom_wfs/ows?service=WFS"+ "&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature"+ '&outputFormat=text/javascript'+ "&typeName=geom_wfs:field"+ "&format_options=callback:loadFeatures"+'&srsname=EPSG:3857';
       // use jsonp: false to prevent jQuery from adding the "callback"
      $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false});
     }
    });


    /**
    * JSONP WFS callback function.
    * @param {Object} response The response object.
    */
    window.loadFeatures = function (response) {
        vectorSource.addFeatures(new     ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response));
        };

    var vectorSource2= new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });    
        
    var formatWFS2 = new ol.format.WFS();
    var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
      featureNS: 'http://geoserver.org/geom_wfs',
      featureType: 'field'
    });

    var polyWFS = function(p,f) {
    switch(p) {
    case 'insert':
        node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction([f],null,null,formatGML);
        break;
    case 'update':
        node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,[f],null,formatGML);
        break;
    case 'delete':
        node = formatWFS2.writeTransaction(null,null,[f],formatGML);
        break;
    }
    s = new XMLSerializer();
    str = s.serializeToString(node);
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8070/geoserver/wfs',{
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: str
        }).done();
        console.log(" polygon features were posted to server");
    }
    case 'btnDrawPolygon':
        interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            type: 'Polygon',
            source: layerVector.getSource()
        });
        map.addInteraction(interaction);
        interaction.on('drawend', function(e) {
          var myAttrValue = prompt("Enter length of area", "");
          var myFeature= e.feature;
          if (myAttrValue != null) {
            myFeature.set('area', myAttrValue);
          }
          polyWFS('insert',e.feature);
        });
        break;
```